# Как сделать чтобы командная строка не закрывалась при нажатии на Enter?

Tags: c++

Решил код откомпилировать но когда вылезает командная строка я нажимаю ентер что бы решилось задание оно закрываеться.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


int main()


{

    int n, 
        w, 
        d1, 
        d2, 
        d3, 
        res; 


    cout << "A three-digit number is given." << endl;
    cout << "Output the number obtained by permutation" << endl;
    cout << "hundreds and tens digits of the original number" << endl;

    cout << "\nEnter a three-digit number: ";
    cin >> n;

    w = n;
    d1 = w / 100,
    d2 = (w / 10) % 10,
    d3 = w % 10;



    res = d2 * 100 + d1 * 10 + d3;

    
    cout << "\nYou entered an octal number: " << n << endl;
    cout << "it is equal to " << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

а то что ниже это код json

```
{
    
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "main.cpp", "-o", "main.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
    
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: и да system("pause") не работает

Comment: cin.get() или _getch() из <conio.h>

Comment: выполните cin >> n. Вы вводите число?

Comment: Можно открыть командную строку ДО запуска приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что `system("pause)"` не работает. Но ладно, в таком случае можете попробовать что-то на подобие этого:

```
string stopStr; // включите <string> и добавьте using namespace std
getline(cin, stopStr);
```

Но это уж моя импровизация, чтобы не повторяться за другими. Конечно компактней и скорее всего быстрее будет тот же `cin.get()` / `_getch()` (<conio.h>)

И постарайтесь использовать табуляцию & не использовать перенос строки просто так. Если бы ваш вопрос был более сложным и было-бы необходимо изучать код - я бы просто проигнорировал его. Думаю, многие бы так-же бы поступили.